# Where does jboss keep the cached servlet version for compiled jsp files

Tags: java, jboss

Where does JBoss keep the compiled jsp files (cached servlets)?  Something similar to the work directory in the Tomcat application server.

I googled to find the answer to this, but I'm not finding any straight answers for it. Sorry,  this is not supposed to be a trick question.

I am seeing the contents of the old versions of my jsp file in the browser. So, If i edit that jsp file, I am not seeing the new one in the browser. So, I thought of removing this cached version to eliminate this issue.

Comment: Which version of JBoss are you referring to?

Comment: server/default/work or server/default/tmp?

Answer (score 4):

Yes... I have C:\jboss-eap-5.1\jboss-as\server\default\work\jboss.web\localhost_\org\apache\jsp

Comment: For JBoss 7.1 its - C:\Jboss\standalone\tmp\work\jboss.web\default-host\<youAppName>\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\pages\

Answer (score 1):

all my compiled jsp files are in this directory : server/default/work/jboss.web/localhost/space/org/apache/jps